# How to set hibernate.format_sql in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `spring-boot` autoconfiguration for database injection, with properties defined:

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

But how can I set the `hibernate.format_sql=true`? Is that not supported by spring boot?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Spring Boot will let you set any available hibernate property using:

`spring.jpa.properties.*`

So `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true` would work as well.

Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-creating-and-dropping-jpa-databases) part of the documentation

Answer (score 23):

If you are using `yml` format to declare Spring Boot properties, you can use:

```
spring:
  datasource:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate.format_sql: true
```

Answer (score 17):

```
jpa:
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update
  show-sql: true
  properties:
    hibernate.format_sql: true
```

Answer (score 10):

This is very much available

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: OK thanks. I wonder why http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/ does not mention this property though...

Answer (score 9):

You can use : `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true`

Apart from the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#), I do follow example from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/mtdevinfo/java/spring-boot) to configure my application. You can find a sample of properties being used in that.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this below properties

> **spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true**

```
    #Turn Statics On
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
    logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug
    
    #Show all queries
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
    logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
```